# How to hide the rows in the table by clicking on button toggle

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to hide the rows with data under the row with header and button until next the row with header and button. clicking one of the +/- button hides/expands all the rows with data content.
http://jsfiddle.net/9ekhuj1q/
Please find the code below-

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Data1</th>
    <th>Data2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header expand">
      <td ><button class="url-button">
      <span class="sign"></span>
      </button></td>
      <td>Header </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr  class="header expand">
      <td ><button class="url-button">
      <span class="sign"></span>
      </button></td>
      <td>Header </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>date</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>data</td>
    <td>data</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

styling

```
table, tr, td, th
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr.header
{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.header .sign:after{
  content:"+";
  display:inline-block;      
}
.header.expand .sign:after{
  content:"-";
 }
```

Click function-

```
$('.url-button').click(function(){
     $('.header').toggleClass('expand').nextUntil('tr.header').slideToggle(100);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another similar way to do the job is to use `event.target`:

```
  $('.url-button').click(function(event){ 
    $(event.target)
      .closest('tr')
      .toggleClass('expand')
      .nextUntil('tr.header')
      .slideToggle(100);
  });
```

There are arguments for either one, but I prefer to use `event.target` over `this`, because it makes the object that `this` refers to immediately obvious. In any case, your original code is selecting all elements with a `.header` class, which as Emiel points out is the source of your problem.

Also, `closest` and `parents` have the same behavior in this case. (If you are interested in how they differ, have a look at [this](https://api.jquery.com/closest/).)

Answer (score 2):

Currently you are selecting all elements with the `header` class whenever you click one of the buttons with `$('.header')`. But you'll want to select the element with the header class that is a grandparent of the button you've just clicked.

Use the `this` keyword to refer to the element you are listening on with the `click()` event listener. That element will be the button that you've clicked on. From there you want to select the element with the `header` class that is a parent of the button using [`.parent('.header')`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/). Now you've selected the correct element and not all the elements with the class.

```
$('.url-button').click(function() {
  $(this)
    .parents('.header')
    .toggleClass('expand')
    .nextUntil('tr.header')
    .slideToggle(100);
});
```